# How to load an internal blender image using OSL?

Tags: osl

OSL has the texture command that we can use to load image files and map in an object. Dfelinto made a nice video about it some years ago. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5N2rnFtSlw

We also have many samples of it in the source of blender:
https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/master/intern/cycles/kernel/shaders/node_image_texture.osl

But how we can load using OSL an blender's internal image? Some created inside it or already loaded using the uv/image editor?

Answer (score 0):

Open shading language try this youtuber code

```
surface environment_node(
    //    filepath input
    string filepath = "find internal blender image path and putin",
    //    surface color output
    output closure color out_color = 0,
    
    )
{
//    Image vector value 
    vector mvdir = I;
//     environment function return color
    color print = environment(filepath,mvdir);
//    surface color output = image color * emission strength
    out_color = print * emission();
}
```

My similar code:

```
surface environment_node(
    //    image color input
    color image = 0,
    //    surface color output
    output closure color out_color = 0,
    
    )
{
//    surface color output = image color * emission strength
    out_color = image * emission();
}
```

[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfxEo.png]

or emission node similer

```
surface environment_node(
    //    image color input
    color image = 0,
    //    strength
    float strength = 2,
    //    surface color output
    output closure color out_color = 0,
    
    )
{
    
//    surface color output = image color * emission strength
    out_color = image * strength * emission();
}
```

[image]

To use it add *Environment* node and plug in the *Color* output to *Image* input.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand the question right. The internal images are values that are generated from coardinates and do not realy exist. You should be able to call the existing method eather direct or indirect.

If that don't worke for you all of the math to generate them isn't that hard to find on the internet.